# How to monitor geth synchronized data？

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, fast-sync

I am using snapshot synchronization mode and have been synchronizing for almost a week. The geth client output is as follows:
[image]

and the lighthouse client output is as follows:
[image]

I checked that 1.5T of data had been downloaded, but when I used the eth.syncing command to check it, it showed that the current block was 0, as shown below:
[image]

And the official website of Ethereum shows that using geth to synchronize in snapshot mode requires about 500G hard disk size. I want to know if I am in the process of synchronization like this? How do I view downloaded data?